# Installed an AR9485 wireless network adapter on my Samsung NP305U1A

Tags: internet

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed on my netbook.
I recently installed the AR9485 card on my netbook but I can't connect to the internet and I don't have a network icon.
I am totally new to Linux. What should I do?

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe ath9k` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I get nothing. When I use sudo lshw I see "network DISABLED" for Ethernet and Wireless interface.

Comment: We wonder why both are disabled. We need the full diagnostics from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: I moved the file over to my Ubuntu desktop and right clicked it to go to Properties and then Permission. I was only able to choose Read and Write not Execute.

Comment: cd ~/Desktop && sudo chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info

Comment: Get this message: cannot access 'wireless-info' : No such file or directory

Comment: Is it not then on your desktop??